# Is the List<T> variable thread safe in my code

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I have the following static class. **Rule** is a custom type. Please confirme that this approach is thread safe for the variable **listToUpdate** which I am passing to each of my rule generating static functions.

```
public static class RulesBO
{
    public static List<Rule> GetRulesForTransaction(int transID)
    {
        List<Rule> toReturn = new List<Rule>();
        GetRulesForSetA(transID,toReturn);
        GetRulesForSetB(transID,toReturn);
    }

    public static void GetRulesForSetA(int transID, List<Rule> listToUpdate)
    {
        /*business logic and finally add/remove elements from listToUpdate*/

    }

    public static void GetRulesForSetB(int transID, List<Rule> listToUpdate)
    {
        /*business logic and finally add/remove elements from listToUpdate*/

    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Edit:
The class RulesBO will be called from ASP.NET. So for each session, for the user's transactionID, the GetRulesForTransaction method will be called to return a list of rules.

Each GetRulesForSetXYZ will make a DB call for the specific transID, get some value, do some checks like <> 100, > 1000 etc and then add a new RULE instance to the variable. Those other methods would be private, with only the first method being public.

Comment: There is not synchronization here - this is certainly **not** thread-safe.

Comment: [What is this thing you call thread safe?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)  You need to be specific about what operations you're performing, and what you expect it to do.  Given that, your code may or may not be meeting your own expectations.  Currently we no know neither what your code is doing, nor what you expect it to be doing.

Comment: Short answer: No. The List in itself is not thread safe. But you're not really doing anything asynchronous or on any other threads here (from what you've shown), so it's all on the same thread.

Comment: `Those other methods would be private, with only the first method being public.`  Yet you made them public in your example...

Comment: No way of knowing without knowing how you're calling these GetRules methods from different threads.  If you're calling GetRulesForTransaction from two different threads, you're getting **two seperate** lists, and there's zero interaction between the threads.  But if your "business logic" (which you haven't shown us) isn't thread safe in some way, or you're using the same GetRules list (or modifying it) from different threads, it might not be thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you stated:

> Each GetRulesForSetXYZ [...] would be private, with only the first method being public.

It means that even if the entry method is called from several different threads at the same time, each of these calls has it's own list.  Each of these lists are only ever accessed from a single thread (at least until they're returned) so you don't have any multi-threaded access to synchronize, so there is no potential for race conditions.

Comment: Thank you for confirming Servy.

Comment: But his business logic could easily be using the lists in ways that are thread unsafe.

Comment: @sylverfyre Sure, and that code is entirely unrelated to the code that he showed us, nor is this code in any way affected by how it's used.  If there is a problem with his program it's not a result of the code he showed us.